# Assign value from another data frame if partially matched: `join` with intern string match

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two data frames. One contains reference values. The other one contains long strings.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ref <- tibble(text  = c("hello",                 "how are you", "example"),
              value = c(1,                       2,             3        ))
df  <- tibble(text  = c("hello my name is john", "how are you", "some other example"))
```

I want to assign the `value`s from `ref` to `df` where `ref$text` appears in `df$text`.

Now, if I wanted exact matching, it would be easy: a join/bind would work perfectly: `left_join(df, ref, by = "text")`. But here, it only matches for the second row (identical) and ignores the partial matches.

In a sense, I want a combination of `left_join()` and `str_detect()` or some other grep-like pattern matching. (Though, I actually don't need regex here, just a match where `*ref$text* == df$text`)

---

Note: I'd appreciate a `tidyverse`/`dplyr` solution, but base R will do as well of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case we could use `fuzzy_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin` package.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)
fuzzy_left_join(df, ref, match_fun = str_detect, by = c(text = "text"))
```

```
  text.x                text.y      value
  <chr>                 <chr>       <dbl>
1 hello my name is john hello           1
2 how are you           how are you     2
3 some other example    example         3
> df
```